# Remove data using datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Goal:
Remove the data in the table Datees by using the variable @remove from dateTbl

The result should be

```
'2016-01-1 00:00:00.000'  
'2016-01-4 00:00:00.000'  
'2016-01-5 00:00:00.000'
```

in table Datees.

It is data

```
'2016-01-3 00:00:00.000'  
'2016-01-5 00:00:00.000'
```

That shall be removed

Problem:
I just can't find a relevant solution to this context when you have the data as a datetime.

Info:
The content of the variable @remove can be different

```
CREATE TYPE dateTbl AS TABLE
( 
    dateID datetime
);


CREATE TABLE Datees
(
    dateID datetime
);

INSERT INTO Datees
VALUES 
('2016-01-1 00:00:00.000'),
('2016-01-2 00:00:00.000'),
('2016-01-3 00:00:00.000'),
('2016-01-4 00:00:00.000'),
('2016-01-5 00:00:00.000')

//------------------------

DECLARE @remove as dateTbl

INSERT INTO @remove
VALUES
('2016-01-3 00:00:00.000'),
('2016-01-4 00:00:00.000')

select a.*
from @remove a
```

Comment: You did a nice job posting readily consumable data. However, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Aaaaand the desired result is?

Comment: delete datees where dateid in (select dateid from @remove)
?

Comment: Probably your question is not clear

Comment: I have updated my message

Comment: Still question is not clear.. Can you provide your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
DELETE d
FROM Datees AS d
JOIN @remove AS t ON d.dateID = t.dateID
```

The above query will remove from table `Datees` all matching records in table variable `@remove`.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote here. This seems to be a great guess at what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Plus1 this is the correct answer, even after multiple readings of the question

Comment: Actually OP is misleading. How would you get 2016-01-04 in the result and 2016-01-02 is removed? That should be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this:

```
delete datees where dateid in (select dateid from @remove)
```

Comment: It is impossible to understand those who downvote without any reason. Probably they do that just because they don't understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you meant:

```
DECLARE @Datees TABLE ( dateID DATETIME );

INSERT  INTO @Datees
VALUES  ( '2016-01-1 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( '2016-01-2 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( '2016-01-3 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( '2016-01-4 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( '2016-01-5 00:00:00.000' );

------------------------

DECLARE @remove AS TABLE ( dateID DATETIME );

INSERT  INTO @remove
VALUES  ( '2016-01-3 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( '2016-01-4 00:00:00.000' );

SELECT  *
FROM    @Datees d
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   @remove r
                     WHERE  r.dateID = d.dateID );
```

For removal:

```
delete
    FROM    @Datees
    WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM   @remove r
                         WHERE  r.dateID = [@datees].dateID );
```

However with DateTime values, it might not be quite easy if the values have time parts too. Then you could utilize casting or converting to string values for comparison. If you have such a need then provide more info.